# Audio and video performance issues in 12.04

Tags: sound, video, multimedia

I've just upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04. 11.10 works fine, but in 12.04 it seems that everything is failing. When I play a video or music, sound (and video) is (faltering?), and YouTube does not work well.

I've tried lots of programs and installed codecs from medibuntu, but it seems there is a problem with the audio driver or even with kernel. I have hardware acceleration via nvidia proprietary driver, if it is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to figure out what your exact problem is without more details, but if your looking for a good paid codec pack I've heard Fluendo Codec is good.  About $40.

I know YouTube does pretty horrible with Flash and I tend to stay away from the browser version of YouTube.  I do try and find things I might like on YouTube on occasion and switch to Miro, but even Miro is new and needs more developers.